# To hide nginx server response header

Tags: nginx, azure-aks

We have installed Nginx ingress controller through Helm. For our app we have maintained setting separately in the config maps. Application is working fine.

As far security concerns, we want to  hide NGinx server and version details from the response header.

We explored a lot and  we found below solutions  -

1. Set server_tokens off. in the NGinx.conf file
2. Set server-tokens = false in the config map file on the AKS portal.

None of the solutions are working currently.

Any Ideas?

[image]